# c# How can I make my gif animation loop in a picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have imported an animated GIF as a resource into a picturebox - unfortunitly it only plays to the end frame and never repeats. Id there something I could do to make it loop continiously. The gif is for my "please wait busy box"

Brad

Comment: Can you post some code? I just tried a sample app with a gif, and it loops without any problems....

Comment: There's really no code to post I just imprted the gif as a resource and pointed the image prop in picturebox to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animated GIFs have a few different settings. Usually, embedded in the file is some data that tells the renderer how the image should be displayed.

This data says how fast the image is animated, if it should loop infinitely, or how many times it should repeat.

There are [several](http://www.jhepple.com/gif_animator.htm) programs [available](http://www.gimp.org/) that you can use to edit an animated GIF and change the looping settings.

First, I'd open your GIF in some app to preview it to see if it loops before trying to alter the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [System.Drawing.ImageAnimator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator.aspx) class helper. You have the Animate, UpdateFrames, and StopAnimate methods to control the loop.